# Calculating the unified atomic mass unit

Tags: nuclear-physics, units, mass-energy, si-units, binding-energy

The masses of [electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron), [proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton) and [neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron) (in SI units) are (approx.):

\begin{equation}
m_e=\text{electron mass}=9.109\times 10^{-31}\ \text{kg}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
m_p=\text{proton mass}=1.673\times 10^{-27}\ \text{kg}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
m_n=\text{neutron mass}=1.675\times 10^{-27}\ \text{kg}
\end{equation}

The [unified atomic mass unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_atomic_mass_unit) ($u$) is defined as one twelfth of the mass of [Carbon-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-12).

\begin{equation}
u=1.661\times 10^{-27}\ \text{kg}
\end{equation}

Now, Carbon-12 contains 6 electrons, 6 protons and 6 neutrons, so the mass of this isotope should be:

\begin{equation}
m=\text{Carbon-12 mass}=6\times(m_e + m_p + m_n)=6\times 3.3489 \times 10^{-27}\ \text{kg}
\end{equation}

Then:

\begin{equation}
\frac{m}{12}=0.5\times 3.3489 \times 10^{-27}\ \text{kg}=1.674 \times 10^{-27}\ \text{kg}
\end{equation}

But this value is different from the value of $u$. Shouldn't $m/12$ be equal to $u$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No.

The difference in that calculation is due to the [nuclear binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy) of the carbon nucleus, which affects the mass via the good old $E=mc^2$. In short, pretty much all nuclei are a bit lighter than their constituent parts would be, which reflects the fact that you would need to put in energy (a.k.a. mass) to split them up into said constituent parts.